# Django-oscar, how to override fronted component

Tags: django-oscar

I am new to Django Oscar, Please refer the attached image, as you know I wanna replace these details with another HTML content.

I have gone through the layouts but could not find it.[image]

https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/tree/releases/3.0/src/oscar/templates/oscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inspect `src/oscar/templates/oscar/catalogue/` *browse.html* and *category.html*. To make changes you need to first copy templates to your template's directory (`yourproject/templates/oscar/*`). Details on how to override templates can be found in [customization docs](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/how_to_customise_templates.html.).

Two HTML fronts are handled by corresponding views that can be found in `/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/views.py`. Particularly, these views are  `CatalogueView` and `ProductCategoryView`. To apply changes to views you need to first fork the app as described in [forking app docs](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/fork_app.html)